# Using a function to perform a repetitive task in R

Tags: r

I have a very large dataset full of dates in 2015. Every single day is listed in this dataset, but some dates are repeated multiple times depending how many incidents happen per day. I want to have a dataset for every day.

So far, I have done:

```
df2 <- split(df1, df1$date)
```

This gives me a list of of every date within list "df2." I can view each day by typing

```
View(df2[["2015-01-01"]])
View(df2[["2015-01-01"]])
Etc.
```

Is there a way to make it so that a function performs the following action:

```
jan1 <- df2[["2015-01-01"]]
jan2 <- df2[["2015-01-02"]]
Etc.
```

Comment: I would ask: what is the purpose or benefit of splitting the data in this way? It's very likely that you can perform whatever analyses you want to do more easily and efficiently by filtering the data, rather than splitting it.

Comment: To see a day-to-day change in the events, which will be plotted on a graph. I could use ggplot and select to plot by color to see some variation in the dates, but there are too many dates for this to be usable. A day-to-day view would allow me to put together a comprehensive timeline of change to graph.

Comment: With your original `df1` you could use something like `df1 %>% filter(between(date, as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-02-01")))` or `df1 %>% filter(date %in% as.Date(c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-11")))` in your ggplot pipeline. With your `df2` list you can still filter / subset by dates, use map & apply functions or just plain for-loop for iterations. What would you do with 365 global variables?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with some of the comments that there might be better ways to manipulate this data for use in `ggplot2`.

However, expanding on **jared_mamrot's** answer, you can also rename those dataframe variables using `lubridate` functions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(dplyr)
df<-
  data.frame(date=c("2023-01-18" ,"2023-01-18" ,"2023-01-18" ,
                  "2021-02-05","2021-02-05","2020-07-21" )) %>%
  tibble::rowid_to_column() %>% 
  mutate(newnames = paste0(lubridate::month(date, label=T), lubridate::day(date))) 

split(df,df$newnames) %>% list2env(envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

This will give you variable names similar to what you specified, but note that this really won't work if you have similar month-and-date pairs on different years. For example, "2023-01-18" and "2020-01-18" would conflict (both would attempt to be assigned to "Jan18") and one would probably be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but here is a potential solution to the question asked:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(date = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-02"),
                  val1 = c(1,2),
                  val2 = c(10, 20))
df2 <- split(df1, df1$date) 

df2[["2015-01-01"]]
#>         date val1 val2
#> 1 2015-01-01    1   10
df2[["2015-01-02"]]
#>         date val1 val2
#> 2 2015-01-02    2   20

list2env(df2, envir = .GlobalEnv)
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

ls()
#> [1] "2015-01-01" "2015-01-02" "df1"        "df2"

# so, there are now 4 dataframes in your global environment
# called "df1", "df2", "2015-01-01" and "2015-01-02"
# you can access the dataframe for each 'day' using backticks,
# e.g. View(`2015-01-01`)

`2015-01-01`
#>         date val1 val2
#> 1 2015-01-01    1   10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>